# Replacing session_register("myusername"); in PHP V5.3.6

Tags: php, function, deprecated

I have the following in my code

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
```

within

```
    <?php

ob_start();
$host="ClubEvents.db.9606426.hostedresource.com"; // Host name 
$username="ClubEventsRead"; // Mysql username 
$password="Pa55word!"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="ClubEvents"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

What is it to be replace by, now that the php function has been deprecated?

I have been reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php but am a little confused, been battling with this all day.

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 5):

Just place the values you want in the $_SESSION array, like:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = "xxx";
```

I'm not seeing you session_start on your code.  Don't forget it.

Comment: ooh, where do I need the session_start function? so do I replace **session_register("myusername");** with **$_SESSION['myusername'] = "xxx";** but whats the value for xxx? $myusername

Comment: Just call the session_start(); function in the first line of your script and it will allow you to use the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: can I ask, when I am putting on my page, my PHP to check the login, does it need to be before or after the Doctype=html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to save your username and the password in the session :

First, usijng "login", "username", "password" in your code is no longer safe, some malicious script try to find these words in your code and play around.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myuse'] = $myuse;
$_SESSION['mypas'] = $mypas;
```